# Proper handling of functions on individual elements of a RecyclerView that contains many elements

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, interface

I am creating a book-themed application in Android. Briefly within my application I have three sections where a user can enter books, specifically: Daleggere, Incorso, Letti (in Italian, but translated would be: to be read, in progress, read). Each of these sections is an android recyclerview with an associated Adapter, also this recyclerview is populated through a Firebase database in real time. I created an interface in the Adapter to perform operations upon clicking buttons that I have in a layout (that can be opened and closed through the *hideShow* function) of each individual recyclerview item. Everything seemed to be working, but today I realized that if I go to add more than 9 books within my list, when I act on one of them, each of my actions is copied for the element 9 times ahead of the one I interacted with (if I open the layout of the first element it also opens the layout of the ninth, if I like the second book it also puts like on the tenth etc.) This problem is not only graphical, but also in the database I am assigned for example "like" to element ten (taking the example from before). This is the Fragment class **CatalogoLetti**:

```
class CatalogoLetti : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCatalogoLettiBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var viewModel: CatalogoViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapterL
    private lateinit var listaLibri: ArrayList<LibriL>
    private lateinit var select: Spinner
    private val sezioni = arrayListOf("Da Leggere","Letti")

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentCatalogoLettiBinding>(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_catalogo_letti, container, false
            )

        binding.backbuttonL.setOnClickListener{
            val navController = findNavController()
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_catalogoLetti_to_catalogoHome)
        }


        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CatalogoViewModel::class.java)

        listaLibri = ArrayList()

        recyclerView = binding.listaLibriLeggere
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        adapter = MyAdapterL(listaLibri)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter


        adapter.setOnCLickItemListener(object : MyAdapterL.onItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {

            }

            override fun hideShow(element: LinearLayout, comment: ImageButton) {
                // Gestione del click per mostrare/nascondere un sezione
                val linearL = element
                val btn = comment
                if(linearL.visibility == View.GONE) {
                    linearL.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_filled_icon)
                }
                else {
                    linearL.visibility = View.GONE
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_icon)
                }

            }

            override fun likeDislike(like: ImageButton, dislike: ImageButton, position: Int) {
                // Gestione del click sui pulsanti "Mi piace" e "Non mi piace"
                val btnLike = like
                val btnDislike = dislike
                val bookPos = position
                val bookId = getIdPos(bookPos)

                btnLike.setOnClickListener {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        if (listaLibri[position].valutazione == 1) {
                            if (bookId != null) {
                                viewModel.removelike(bookId)
                                btnLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.pollice_icon)
                                listaLibri[position].valutazione = 0
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (bookId != null) {
                                viewModel.like(bookId)
                                btnLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_click_icon)
                                btnDislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.pollice_icon)
                                listaLibri[position].valutazione = 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                btnDislike.setOnClickListener {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        if (listaLibri[position].valutazione == 2) {
                            if (bookId != null) {
                                viewModel.removelike(bookId)
                                btnDislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.pollice_icon)
                                listaLibri[position].valutazione = 0
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (bookId != null) {
                                viewModel.dislike(bookId)
                                btnDislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike_click)
                                btnLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.pollice_icon)
                                listaLibri[position].valutazione = 2
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            override fun comment(recensione: TextInputLayout, position: Int) {
                // Gestione dell'inserimento di un commento su un libro letto
                val commento = recensione.editText

                if (commento != null) {
                    commento.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                        override fun beforeTextChanged(
                            s: CharSequence?,
                            start: Int,
                            count: Int,
                            after: Int
                        ) {

                        }

                        override fun onTextChanged(
                            s: CharSequence?,
                            start: Int,
                            before: Int,
                            count: Int
                        ) {

                        }

                        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                            if(s != null && s.isNotEmpty() && s.last() == '\n'){
                                s.replace(s.length - 1, s.length, "")
                                val review = s.toString()
                                val bookPos = position

                                val bookId = getIdPos(bookPos)
                                if (bookId != null) {
                                    viewModel.comment(review, bookId)

                                }
                            }

                        }


                    })
                }
            }
            override fun dettaglioBook(cover: ImageButton, position: Int) {
                // Gestione del click sulla copertina per visualizzare i dettagli di un libro letto
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val libro = async {getLibro(position)}

                    val action =
                        CatalogoLettiDirections.actionCatalogoLettiToLibroLetto(
                            libro.await()!!,
                            "catalogoLetti"
                        )
                    findNavController().navigate(action)
                }
            }

            override fun remove(button: ImageButton, position: Int) {
                // Gestione del click sul pulsante rappresentante una x per rimuovere un libro letto
                val dButton = button
                val bookPos = position
                val bookId = getIdPos(bookPos)
                dButton.setOnClickListener {
                    var dialog: AlertDialog? = null
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                    val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_elimina, null)
                    val btnConfirm = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_confirm)
                    val btnCancel = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_cancel)
                    builder.setView(dialogView)

                    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener {
                        if (bookId != null) {
                            viewModel.removeBook(bookId, "letti")
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "Libro eliminato con successo!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "Errore nell'eliminazione!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                        dialog?.dismiss()
                    }

                    btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
                        dialog?.dismiss()
                    }

                    dialog = builder.create()
                    dialog?.show()
                }
            }

        })

        viewModel.checkBookCatalogo()
        viewModel.libriLetti.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { LettiBooksList ->
                loadBooks(LettiBooksList)
            })

    }

    private fun loadBooks(books: List<LibriL>?){
        // Carica i libri letti nella lista listaLibri
        listaLibri.clear()
        if (books != null) {
            listaLibri.addAll(books)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun getIdPos(position : Int): String? {
        // Ottiene l'ID del libro in una deteerminata posizione
        if(listaLibri.isNotEmpty()){
            val bookId = listaLibri[position].id
            return bookId
        }
        return null
    }

    private suspend fun getLibro(position: Int): LibriL? {
        // Ottiene i dettagli di un libro letto dal database Firebase
        val bookId = listaLibri[position].id
        var bookD: LibriL? = null

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null) {
            val cUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
            val database =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://booktique-87881-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/")
            val usersRef = database.reference.child("Utenti")
            val childRef = usersRef.child(cUser.uid)
            val catalogoRef = childRef.child("Catalogo")
            val lettiRef = catalogoRef.child("Letti")

            if (bookId != null) {
                val dataSnapshot = lettiRef.child(bookId).get().await()
                bookD = dataSnapshot.getValue(LibriL::class.java)
            }
        }
        return bookD
    }

}
```

And this is the Adapter, **MyAdapterL**:

```
class MyAdapterL (private val listaLibri : ArrayList<LibriL>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterL.MyViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var bListener : onItemClickListener

    interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
        fun hideShow(element: LinearLayout, comment : ImageButton)

        fun likeDislike(like: ImageButton, dislike : ImageButton, position: Int)

        fun comment(recensione : TextInputLayout, position: Int)

        fun dettaglioBook(cover: ImageButton, position: Int)

        fun remove(button: ImageButton, position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnCLickItemListener(listener : onItemClickListener){
        bListener = listener
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View, listener: onItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val cover : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverL)
        val titolo : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titoloL)
        val autore : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.autoreL)
        val btnLike : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeL)
        val btnDislike : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dislikeL)
        val comment : TextInputLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout)

        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
            }

            itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.commentL).setOnClickListener {
                listener.hideShow(itemView.findViewById(R.id.hideLayoutL), itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentL))
                listener.likeDislike(btnLike,btnDislike,absoluteAdapterPosition)
                listener.comment(comment,absoluteAdapterPosition)
            }

            itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.coverL).setOnClickListener{
                listener.dettaglioBook(itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverL),bindingAdapterPosition)

            }

            itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.deleteL).setOnClickListener {
                listener.remove(itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteL),bindingAdapterPosition)
            }

        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.lista_libri_letti,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView,bListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = listaLibri[position]

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(currentItem.copertina)
            .into(holder.cover)
        holder.titolo.text = abbreviaInfo(currentItem?.titolo ?: "",25)

        holder.autore.text = abbreviaInfo(currentItem?.autori ?: "",25)

        if(currentItem?.valutazione == 1)
            holder.btnLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_click_icon)
        else if(currentItem?.valutazione == 2)
            holder.btnDislike.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike_click)

        holder.comment.editText?.setText(currentItem?.recensione ?: "")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listaLibri.size
    }

    fun abbreviaInfo(stringa: String, lunghezzaMassima: Int): String {
        return if (stringa.length <= lunghezzaMassima) {
            stringa
        } else {
            val sottostringa = stringa.take(lunghezzaMassima)
            "$sottostringa..."
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that this problem was due to the fact that in all my functions I use the position of the element within my list and that actually the recyclerview to save memory only counted 9 elements at a time. But by printing the position of the element in position 12 for example, the result is correct and it is 12, moreover by clicking on the cover of each of the books (elements of my recyclerview) I have the possibility to enter a detail page of it. But here, to my surprise, there is no problem and even if I click on the cover of the book in position 20 it opens the right book. So I don't know at this point maybe the problem is in the init of my adapter, when I go to open the layout that allows me to perform the various actions on the book here:

```
itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.commentL).setOnClickListener {
                listener.hideShow(itemView.findViewById(R.id.hideLayoutL), itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentL))
                listener.likeDislike(btnLike,btnDislike,absoluteAdapterPosition)
                listener.comment(comment,absoluteAdapterPosition)
            }
```

I'm relatively new to the Android world, thanks a lot in advance!